# .htaccess redirect every "yearly" page to same name subdomain..

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, archive

I need redirect "year-slug" post/pages to same name subdomain, like this:

http://domain.com/2013/post-name/  to http://2013.domain.com/2013/post-name/

this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/.+$ http://$1.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```